# git branch checkout using sourcetree tool is taking more than 45 minutes

Tags: github, sourcetree

I am checking out a git branch using sourcetree tool and its taking a way long - 45 minutes.

> **command getting executed** 
> git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false clone --branch mybranch --recursive mygitrepourl
>
> **size of branch**: 670 MB

please help me to understand why its taking so long to checkout.

Comment: Thank you all for your support.
The issue was with network - it was too slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that a large file (possible a binary one) has been stored (sometimes in multiple versions) in the git repo.

If that is the case, you might have to [remove that file from the repo history](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-files-from-a-repository-s-history/) and (after communicating with other users of that repo) do a `git push --force`.

Also you might consider using [Git Large-File Storage (Git LFS)](https://git-lfs.github.com/) for those big files.

Comment: Thanks @VonC. My repository is having binary files (dependent dlls). Your suggestion will help me to look take care of binary files.

Answer (score 0):

Using `--depth 1` for clone only lastest commit [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone)

`git clone yourlink --depth 1`

With bitbucket. In Advance option `Clone depth`: 1